# How to efficiently locate and save pixels with a certain value using OPENCV?

Tags: python, performance, opencv

I'm using OpenCV to search through a binary image and extract all the white pixels into a list.  
However, my process takes roughly 10-12 seconds, and I'm trying to maximize efficiency as much as possible.

Here's what I have (`thresh2` is the image after thresholding):

```
h,w=thresh2.shape[:2]
WhitePix=[]
for in range(0,h):
   TstVal=thresh2[i]
   if TstVal.max()=255:
      for j in range(0,w):
         if thresh2[i,j]==255:
            WhitePix.append([i,j])
```

I check each row to see if it has a white pixel, and if it does, I append it to my list.

*Is there any function in OpenCV to speeds this search?*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in two ways:

1) Using Numpy functions

```
pixelpoints = np.transpose(np.nonzero(mask))
```

2) Using OpenCV functions

```
pixelpoints = cv2.findNonZero(mask)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `thresh2` is a numpy array. If this is the case, why not use numpy filtering directly, which is far more efficient: `thresh2.nonzero()` will return the indexes of white pixels. You can then use it directly to mask your array: `thresh2[thresh2.nonzero()]` or whatever you want to do next...

Generally speaking, in python, loops that can be avoided should.

Comment: yeah, I don't really code, just needed to transfer some matlab script into python, thanks though